# Clicked on image jQuery - function doesn't work after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wrote this code for application which is using nodejs:

```
socket.on('daneTury', function (dataa){
            var gracze = "";
            $("#informacje").hide("slow");
            $("#odpowiedziGraczy").empty();

            for(i = 0; i < $scope.gracze.length; i++){
                var lp = i + 1;
                var panstwo = typeof dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].panstwo !== 'undefined' ? dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].panstwo : "";
                var miasto = typeof dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].miasto !== 'undefined' ? dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].miasto : "";
                var imie = typeof dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].imie !== 'undefined' ? dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].imie : "";
                var rzecz = typeof dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].rzecz !== 'undefined' ? dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].rzecz : "";
                var samochod = typeof dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].samochod !== 'undefined' ? dataa[$scope.gracze[i].text].samochod : "";

                gracze += "<tr><td>" + lp + "</td>" + "<td>" + $scope.gracze[i].text + "</td><td>" + panstwo + "</td><td><img id='wrong' src='img/wrong.png' data-ng-click='zle()' alt='wrong'></td><td>" + miasto + "</td><td><img id='wrong' src='img/wrong.png' alt='wrong'></td><td>" + rzecz + "</td><td><img id='wrong' src='img/wrong.png' alt='wrong'></td><td>" + imie + "</td><td><img id='wrong' src='img/wrong.png' alt='wrong'></td><td>" + samochod + "</td><td><img id='wrong' src='img/wrong.png' alt='wrong'></td></tr>";
            }

            $("#odpowiedziGraczy").append("<strong>Odpowiedzi reszty graczy:</strong><div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-striped'><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Nik</th><th>Panstwo</th><th></th><th>Misato</th><th></th><th>Rzecz</th><th></th><th>Imie</th><th></th><th>Samochod</th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody>" + gracze + "</tbody></table></div>");
            $("#odpowiedziGraczy").show("slow");
        });
```

My question is about: `<img id='wrong' src='img/wrong.png' alt='wrong'>`. Why when i clicked on this image function "zle" doesn't work?

Comment: data-ng-click='zle()' likely refers to an AngularJS directive, I would expect a function with that name to exist on a controller, do you have any more information?

Comment: i wrote this function:         $scope.zle = function(){
            alert("aaa");
        }; and when i add <img id='wrong' src='img/wrong.png' alt='wrong'> into html file everything works good but still doesn't work in table which is generated with using append

Comment: I think that because you are appending after AngularJS has run over the page and added all its linking functions is why its not working.

Comment: do you know how can i fixed it? Now i tryed make it with using jQuery:  
            $.each($("#wrong"), function( index, value ) {
                $(this).click(function() {
                    $(this).hide("slow");
                });
            }); but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `$compile` elements you create dynamically, to make `ng-click` or other angular directives work.

After `$("#odpowiedziGraczy").show("slow");` you should use:

```
$compile(angular.element("#odpowiedziGraczy").contents())(scope);
```

Don't forget to inject `$compile` service into your directive/controller.

More about `$compile`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile